# Extended child object inheritance in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, inheritance

I'm converting a legacy application to use hibernate and have a seemingly simple problem which I can't find an answer for. I have a basic object where all fields map to columns of one table then a number of objects which need to inherit from this basic object and have different transient fields.

```html
@javax.persistence.Table(name = "order", schema = "PUB", catalog = "SUB")
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "DISCRIMINATOR", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
@DiscriminatorValue("OrderEntity")

public class OrderEntity {

    protected String orderNumber;

    @javax.persistence.Column(name = "order_number", nullable = true, insertable = true, updatable = true, length = 24)
    @Id
    public String getOrderNumber() {
        return orderNumber;
    }

    public void setOrderNumber(String orderNumber) {
        this.orderNumber = orderNumber;
    }

    protected String orderType;

    @javax.persistence.Column(name = "order_type", nullable = true, insertable = true, updatable = true, length = 16)
    @Basic
    public String getOrderType() {
        return orderType;
    }

    public void setOrderType(String orderType) {
        this.orderType = orderType;
    }

    protected String client;

    @javax.persistence.Column(name = "client", nullable = true, insertable = true, updatable = true, length = 60)
    @Basic
    public String getClient() {
        return client;
    }

    public void setClient(String client) {
        this.client = client;
    }

}
```

```html
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("ExtOrderEntity")

public class ExtOrderEntity extends OrderEntity
{

    protected transient String received;
    protected transient String rcvdTime;
    protected transient String rcvdDate;

    @Transient
    public String getReceived()
    {
        return received;
    }

    public void setReceived(String received)
    {
        this.received = received;
    }

    @Transient
    public String getRcvdTime()
    {
        return rcvdTime;
    }

    public void setRcvdTime(String rcvdTime)
    {
        this.rcvdTime = rcvdTime;
    }

    @Transient
    public String getRcvdDate()
    {
        return rcvdDate;
    }

    public void setRcvdDate(String rcvdDate)
    {
        this.rcvdDate = rcvdDate;
    }

}
```

Obviously the actual objects are a lot bigger. So the discriminator column is redundant as all rows could be either type of object. Need to be able to cast to basic object to use shared methods. Have tried using discriminator column but can't seem to stop hibernate from trying to persist the value or find it on database even when declared transient. If i use an existing field it tells me I have to make the field insertable=false, updatable=false which is no good if I want to save one of the extended objects.
    Would appreciate any help.

Comment: Got round it using @MappedSuperClass plus an interface.